# How to install pantheon desktop on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to install pantheon desktop on ubuntu server 20.04. I've looked at a few guides online and they all tend to suggest the below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

After going through these steps and i reboot ubuntu, I now have a GUI which I didn't have before. However when I login and I select my desktop environment I just have the two options of "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu on Wayland". Why is Pantheon not showing here?

Comment: I am fairly sure you need to uninstall Wayland first.   I wound up not bothering to change desktops in Ubuntu. I use Kali with XFCE instead..  I wanted to be able to go back to gnome so I did not really wish to uninstall Wayland

Comment: I started with ubuntu server without GUI, the two desktop options came as a result of running the above